# byobu in ubuntu server 14.xx not recognizing Ctrl + F# combinations

Tags: server, shortcut-keys, byobu

My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> keys are not registering in byobu.  I installed openbox to check it on a gnome-terminal and it does work there but I prefer to not use a windows manager.  I've checked my keyboard layout, the <kbd>F#</kbd> key .tmux files, and verified that I'm using tmux instead of screen.

Q: anyone have this problem and a solution?

Q: if not, does anyone know off hand what the command is to split a screen horizontally in byobu?